# managed c to call an unmanaged c dll , unresolved token

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, unmanaged, managed

I have 1 native c++ dll, CppApp, another project is managed c++, GatWayLibrary, with /clr 
In GatewayLibrary, I called functions from native CppApp dll. 
but I got unresolve token errors. 
Here are my code snips:

```
CppApp.h
=========
#ifdef CPPAPP_EXPORTS
#define CPPAPP_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CPPAPP_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class CPPAPP_API CppApp 
{
public:
    CppApp();
     ~CppApp();

     ContextManager & contextMgr() { return m_rplContextMng; }
     INativeListener* m_listener;

     void registerListener(INativeListener* listener)
     {
          m_listener = listener;
     }
...........
 }
```

In separate project, GateWaylibrary, wrap the native dll as

```
#include "../CppApp/CppApp.h"
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;


#pragma comment(lib, "CppApp.lib")

namespace GatewayLibrary{

    //.net equvelant of the argument class
public ref class DotNetEventArg{
internal:

//contructor takes native version of argument to transform
DotNetEventArg(const NativeCPPArgs& args) {
....
...
}
```

the managed c++ has the linking errors as unresolved tokens for all the function calls from the native c++.

I did include the CppApp.lib as Additional Dependencies
and the directory. 
Can anyone please help? many thanks ahead.

Edit: 
here is of the place I called the native c++ 
    `GatewayLibrary::EventGateway::EventGateway()
    {
        nativeCode_ = new CppApp();

```
    //note; using 'this' in ctor is not a good practice
    nativeListener_ = new NativeListenerImp(this);

    //register native listener
    nativeCode_->registerListener(nativeListener_);
}`
```

Comment: You might want to consider using an abstract interface over exporting the entire class, if that is acceptable, I can show you a quick example. Otherwise there isn't enough code in your example to figure out what is wrong, which import is failing to load, how do you call those functions? etc.

Comment: Hi Radu, thanks, I just edited the question, add sample function which I called native c++ func.

Comment: Everything seems to be in order, I remember having an issue like this a while ago when I accidentally used a 32bit lib for a 64bit build, can you check if the output architectures match ?

Comment: I checked the dll in Cygwin, by file CppApp.dll

Comment: and it gives                                                                                 CppApp.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows

Comment: sorry, hit for newline but posted right away
I meant both the dll s are in 64 bit

Comment: The word "Cygwin" is very troublesome.  You cannot import classes from a DLL that was created in a non-Microsoft compiler.  C++ compilers to not agree about name mangling conventions.